# While Loop Doesn't Fit all the Checks

Tags: java

I have a coding problem that asks:

We want to make a row of bricks that is goal inches long. We have a number of small bricks (1 inch each) and big bricks (5 inches each). Return true if it is possible to make the goal by choosing from the given bricks. This is a little harder than it looks and can be done without any loops.

And examples are:

L511_makeBricks(3, 1, 8) → true

L511_makeBricks(3, 1, 9) → false

L511_makeBricks(3, 2, 10) → true.

I wrote the following code:

```
public boolean L511_makeBricks(int small, int big, int goal) {
  int smalln;
  int bign;
  smalln = 0;
  bign = 0;
  while (smalln <= small){
    while (bign<= big) {
      if (smalln + bign*5 == goal){
        return true;
      }else{
        bign = bign + 1;
      }
    }
    bign = 0 ;
    smalln = smalln + 1;
  }
  return false;
}
```

When I run the problem, it says that it is correct for every test run except "other" where it runs more examples to check if it is right.

I can't see where my code is going wrong. What my code is supposed to do is go through each possible combination of small and bigs bricks.

Comment: Where is recursion ?

Comment: Sorry, maybe it's not recursion. I changed the title

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
public boolean L511_makeBricks(int small, int big, int goal) {
    if (big * 5 + small < goal) {
        return false;
    }
    return goal % 5 <= small;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It works, but I'm want to know why my code doesn't work.

Comment: Seems kind of crazy trying to follow and work out what is wrong with your loopy code that tries to implement basic multiplication and addition, in a long winded way. In any case, no need for a test in the inner loop, as you're not checking smaller factors of supplied parameters but instead just do the multiplication and addition and finally test against goal. no resets of bign etc.

Comment: @FoxEvolved What cases does it fail in? I can't immediately see what part of your code fails.

Comment: @MihirKekkar It just fails in the "other cases" category. In the 30 or so cases they show, it all works.

Comment: @FoxEvolved the only thing I can think of could be if whatever program is running your solution has only been given a certain amount of time to test each case before automatically failing it and your nested while loops are going over this limit for large inputs.